# Print characters and their frequencies in order of occurrence in a given string but i cant' understand line "freq[str[i] - 'a']++; "

Tags: c++, lexicographic

[**Print characters and their frequencies in order of occurrence**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-characters-frequencies-order-occurrence/)

This is the whole program link if you want to know other details

Below is program

```
void printCharWithFreq(string str) 
  { 

int n = str.size(); 

// 'freq[]' implemented as hash table 
int freq[SIZE]; 

// initialize all elements of freq[] to 0 
memset(freq, 0, sizeof(freq)); 

// accumulate freqeuncy of each character in 'str' 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    freq[str[i] - 'a']++;   //**cannot understand this line**

// traverse 'str' from left to right 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

    // if frequency of character str[i] is not 
    // equal to 0 
    if (freq[str[i] - 'a'] != 0) { 

        // print the charcter along with its 
        // frequency 
        cout << str[i] << freq[str[i] - 'a'] << " "; 

        // update frequency of str[i] to 0 so  
        // that the same character is not printed  
        // again 
        freq[str[i] - 'a'] = 0; 
    } 
  }
```

}

Comment: `str[i] - 'a'` _normalizes_ the `str[i]` values based to zero. Thes will yield `0` for `'a'`, `1` for `'b'`, `2` for `'c'`, aso.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `std::map<char, int>` ? This could be done correctly in 2-4 lines of code. `std::map<char, int> occurrences;  for (const auto& c : str) { occurrences[c]++; }` should be a good starting point.

Comment: Look at the integer values of characters: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- that's true for some character sets, but not for all.

Comment: @RichardCritten -- those are values for the **ASCII** character encoding. Yes, it's widely used -- you haven't seen any others -- but it is not the only one, and neither C nor C++ requires programs to use ASCII.

Comment: @pete Apparently that was assuming an ASCII character set, but _geeks-for-geeks_ assumes a lot all day long :P.

Comment: Am I the only one hung on the `memset` an array in C++?

Comment: @bolov As mentioned there's a lotta crap to be found at _geeks-for-geeks_. Seems they're more concentrating about being _geeky_, than posting solid code.

Comment: I'm hung up on assuming a "character" is a lowercase Basic Latin letter, which I guess is where the 'a' comes in.

Answer (score 3):

So, when trying to understand code, start inside-out, just like in algebra:
`freq[str[i] - 'a']++;`
All characters are represented as integer values. Even Unicode's extended alphabet includes the old ASCII table as values 0-255 (how characters were represented as 8-bit integers).

ASCII values table:

[image]

`str[i]` is the i-th letter of the string, which is the same as an array in C/C++, so it can be accessed using bracket notation from `[0]` to `[n]`, where `n==str.size();`

`freq[]` is the array in which we will store the frequency counts for each of the letters, initialized to 0 in each slot by the `memset(freq, 0, sizeof(freq));` command. The index of each slot in the `freq[]` array corresponds to a number representation of "how much bigger that letter is than lowercase 'a'". (Note: I presume from this implementation that the string input `str` will be all lowercase letters (no uppercase, punctuation, or digits). So, `freq[0]` corresponds to the counts for the character that is "0 bigger than 'a'", or 'a' itself. The counts for 'b' can be found in `freq[1]`, those for 'c' in `freq[2]`, and so on until freq[25] which holds the counts for z.

So, `freq[str[i] - 'a']` addresses the slot in the `freq[]` array which corresponds to the appropriate letter. *We take the value in that slot and increment it by 1 because we just discovered that character at str[i]*. Remember, at the beginning of the first for loop, which contains the line of code we are analyzing, all the counts are 0. The way to write that is the piece of code you quoted: `freq[str[i] - 'a']++;`

Comment: You said "when trying to understand code, start inside-out".  That made my day.  I have been teaching students to do that for over 20 years and to hear it here is reassuring.  thank you!!

Comment: It's humbling to know someone with your experience appreciates my teaching style, Dr. T. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood the concept